# Search query perfomance?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to perform a search operation with different conditions.

for example.

```
Select * from test where field1="temp";
```

if return 0 records then check for

```
Select * from test where field2="temp";
```

if return 0 records then check for

```
Select * from test where field3="temp";
```

and so on. Each time query field is changed. if result set is not empty then return result set.

I want to know that what is the best way to perform this task with good performance?

1. create Mysql Function which check for each condition and return.
2. Check this in JAVA source code? (Sounds not a good idea for me).
3. Is there any other way to perform this in a single select query?
4. Any other suggestion? I am using basic JDBC servlet and MySql.

Comment: It sounds like you have a very badly denormalised data structure.

Comment: How many fields are there to check for? How many rows will your table have (approx.)?

Comment: It is one kind of priority search for example query string is "Temp" then query on fields like First_name, Last_name, addrss, city, and so on but with priority. there is maximum 10 fields. and rows is around 10K

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQL `CASE`:

```
CASE case_value
  WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
  [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
  [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

or

```
CASE
  WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
  [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
  [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Also, a stored procedure to do this would be good.

Comment: But this works for one column at a time, doesn't it? Difficulty is that there are potentially many columns involved.

Comment: @mthmulders Not necessary, follow the link, there are other formats as well.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in Java dont sound bad to me.

```
private List<Object> retrieveData() {
    String[] fields = {"field1","field2"};
    String value = "foo";
    List<Object> results;
    for(String field : fields){
        results = getResults(field, value);
        if(!results.isEmpty()){
            break;
        }
    } 
    return results;
}

public List<Object> getResults(String field, String value){
    // Use Prepared statement here
    List<Object> results = "Select * from test where " + field + " = " + value;
    return results;
}
```

Not sure about the performance of this against the doing the same through query.